# как сделать thumbnails у записей хорошего качества?

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, wordpress-плагины

[image: r]

Как мне избавиться от мыльных thumbnails в записях wordpress ? чтобы они были хорошего качества ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделайте что-то вроде

```
add_filter('jpeg_quality', create_function('', 'return 100;'));
```

100 - это максимальное качество, можно поставить меньше

Фильтр будет работать только для новых изображений. Уже загруженные в медиабиблиотеку можно пересоздать при помощи какого-нибудь плагина, например, **Regenerate Thumbnails**

Comment: Чет не помогло(

Comment: Старые миниатюры придётся пересоздать заново, они уже пережаты со старым качеством. Убедитесь, кстати, что размер миниатюр (ширина и высота) соответствует размерам контейнера, может они у вас просто масштабируются браузером и за счёт этого теряют в визуальном качестве

Comment: Спасибо, теперь работает )